# Handling Cookies while scraping with Python

Tags: python, cookies, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the links from the careers page on a college website, and I am getting this error.

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
>   The last 30x error message was:
>   Moved Temporarily

I think this is because the site has a session cookie.  After doing a bit of reading, there seems to be many ways to get around this (Requests, http.cookiejar, Selenium/PhantomJs), but I don't know how to incorporate these solutions into my scraping program.

This is my scraping program.  It's written in Python 3.6 with BeautifulSoup4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://jobs.fanshawec.ca/applicants/jsp/shared/search/SearchResults_css.jsp")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select(".ft0 a")
ads = []

for i in data:
    link = i.get('href')
    ads.append(link)

for job in ads:
    print(job)
    print('')
```

When I clear the cookies in my browser and manually go to the page I'm trying to scrape (https://jobs.fanshawec.ca/applicants/jsp/shared/search/SearchResults_css.jsp), I'm taken to a different page.  Once I have the cookie though, I can go directly to the SearchResults page that I want to scrape.

This is the cookie:

[image: This is the cookie]

Any thoughts on how I can deal with this cookie?

Comment: It might also require javascript, in which case you would need to read the HTML via something like selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `requests`-module:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()
req = session.get("https://jobs.fanshawec.ca/applicants/jsp/shared/search/SearchResults_css.jsp")
req.raise_for_status()  # omit this if you dont want an exception on a non-200 response
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select(".ft0 a")
ads = []

for i in data:
    link = i.get('href')
    ads.append(link)

for job in ads:
    print(job)
    print('')
```

However, i am not getting any output, which is probably due to ads being empty.
I hope this helps you,

Answer (score 0):

The website you are trying to access is probably testing for both cookies and Javascript to be present. Python does provide a [CookieJar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html?highlight=build_opener#module-http.cookiejar) library but this will not be enough if javascript is also mandatory.

Instead you could use Selenium to get the HTML. It is a bit like a remote control for an existing browser, and can be used as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

url = "https://jobs.fanshawec.ca/applicants/Central?delegateParameter=searchDelegate&actionParameter=showSearch&searchType=8192"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary())
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

data = soup.select(".ft0 a")
ads = []

for i in data:
    link = i.get('href')
    ads.append(link)

for job in ads:
    print(job)
```

(Also look at PhantomJS for a headless solution)

Which would give you your links starting as follows:

```
/applicants/Central?delegateParameter=applicantPostingSearchDelegate&actionParameter=getJobDetail&rowId=174604&c=%2BWIX1RV817HeJUg7cnxxnQ%3D%3D&pageLoadIdRequestKey=1490116459459&functionalityTableName=8192&windowTimestamp=null
/applicants/Central?delegateParameter=applicantPostingSearchDelegate&actionParameter=getJobDetail&rowId=174585&c=4E7TSRVJx7jLG39iR7HvMw%3D%3D&pageLoadIdRequestKey=1490116459459&functionalityTableName=8192&windowTimestamp=null
/applicants/Central?delegateParameter=applicantPostingSearchDelegate&actionParameter=getJobDetail&rowId=174563&c=EyCIe7a8xt0a%2BLp4xqtzaw%3D%3D&pageLoadIdRequestKey=1490116459459&functionalityTableName=8192&windowTimestamp=null
/applicants/Central?delegateParameter=applicantPostingSearchDelegate&actionParameter=getJobDetail&rowId=174566&c=coZCMU3091mmz%2BE7p%2BHNIg%3D%3D&pageLoadIdRequestKey=1490116459459&functionalityTableName=8192&windowTimestamp=null
/applicants
```

Note: To use Selenium, you will need to [install it](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html), as it is not part of the default Python libraries:

```
pip install selenium
```

Comment: I ran your code, and I got these errors: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'                                                            During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
'geckodriver'>selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: I downloaded geckodriver, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Mine happens to be in my Python folder `C:\Python27\geckodriver.exe`

Comment: Do I have to put the path in the code?  I tried adding this to no success: binary = FirefoxBinary('I put the path in here')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

Comment: I'll spend some more time with the Selenium docs.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Mine script works "as is". I don't remember putting FIrefox in my path. I think there is also a Chrome binding if that would be better? (You obviously need to have the browsers installed)